# Learning Python for Machine learning for mathematical student

Tags: machine-learning, python, references

I am familiar with mathematics but not with Python for machine learning. I have been reading books to code, but they tend to avoid talking about maths to speak to larger audience. They are well written indeed, but I would like to take advantage of my interest for mathematics to begin to learn python for machine learning. Do you know a book which provides it?

For example I'm okay to use stochastic gradient descent function of scikit-learn but if at least they give us a mathematical explanation about it (it's just an example, it's the same for relatively advances statistical concepts). Or it's also nice to code the mathematical concept you just learnt.

Comment: [This](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) is the only book I'm aware of that somewhat fits your criteria. Its goal, however, is to explain Deep Learning and Neural Networks (through python examples), but not to explicitly teach the Machine Learning python ecosystem. Other than that there are some math-heavy books (e.g. [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-84858-7)) and some more technically-oriented books that avoid math altogether (e.g. [Francois Chollet's book](https://www.manning.com/books/deep-learning-with-python).

Comment: https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook for python, numpy sklearn pandas etc

Comment: @seanv507 : Thank you for this book but it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: @Djib2011 : I don't understand why do you propose me a book " Francois Chollet's book" that avoids maths ?

Comment: I didn't recommend it, I just mentioned it to show the duality.

Comment: I finished Michael Nielsen's book first chapter and it doesn't answer to the question even though it was interesting it was cleary designed in the goal the reader doesn't need to really understand maths.